# Is there any algorithm for calculating area of a shape given co-ordinates that define the shape?

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry

So I have some function that receives N random `2D` points.

Is there any algorithm to calculate area of the shape defined by the input points?

Comment: What is your question exactly and what kind of square are you talking about?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking for, the minimum bounding square/rectangle maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "counting square of shape"? Do you mean the area? If so, what method do you use to determine what the "shape" is?

Comment: What size is N likely to be? Are there any performance constraints?

Comment: I ment area http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area

Comment: :) @Mark Byers: we are far away from performance tweaks because we are far away from the question?

Comment: Since you don't have a polygon, you need to build one. I've detailed this in my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-2d-polygon ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want to [calculate the area of a polygon](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/polyarea/)?

(Taken from link, converted to C#)

```
class Point { double x, y; } 

double PolygonArea(Point[] polygon)
{
   int i,j;
   double area = 0; 

   for (i=0; i < polygon.Length; i++) {
      j = (i + 1) % polygon.Length;

      area += polygon[i].x * polygon[j].y;
      area -= polygon[i].y * polygon[j].x;
   }

   area /= 2;
   return (area < 0 ? -area : area);
}
```

Comment: I dream about heavenly bodies ;)

Comment: Hmm, nice but does this take care of concavity (tweesting polygone :) ?

Comment: @manitra yes it does http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=geometry1&module=Static

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, there is no ready-made polygon: you will need to create one.

Comment: I know this may not be the place to ask but... How would I apply this concept to a polygon made with geodetic vertices (lat lon). Do I need to do a projection to the cartesian coordinate system or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Defining the "area" of your collection of points may be hard, e.g. if you want to get the smallest region with straight line boundaries which enclose your set then I'm not sure how to proceed. Probably what you want to do is calculate the area of the convex hull of your set of points; this is a standard problem, a description of the problem with links to implementations of solutions is given by Steven Skiena at the [Stony Brook Algorithms repository](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/convex-hull.shtml). From there one way to calculate the area (it seems to me to be the obvious way) would be to triangulate the region and calculate the area of each individual triangle.

Comment: The "smallest region with straight line boundaries" has area 0 and encloses a minimum spanning tree.

Comment: Yep, fair enough comment. I suppose there may be reasonable constraints that can be put on this problem to give solutions other than the convex hull (e.g. allowing for "large" holes by allowing for arbitrary edges with the restriction that the number of edges is O(n^{1/2})), but any such problem is likely to be extremely hard to solve.

Comment: Picking nits here, but the region with the shortest straight line boundaries would actually be a Steiner tree, which is in general shorter than the MST.

Comment: The only guarantee you can make with the area of convex hull is that it will be an **upper bound**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timothy Chan's algorithm for finding convex hull in nlogh, where n is the number of points, h is the number of convex hull vertices. If you want an easy algorithm, go for Graham scan.

Also, if you know that your data is ordered like a simple chain, where the points don't cross each other, you can use Melkman's algorithm to compute convex hull in O(N).

Also, one more interesting property of convex hull is that, it has the minium perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not directly imply that there's a ready-made polygon (which is assumed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432428/is-there-any-algorithm-for-calculating-area-of-a-shape-given-co-ordinates-that-de/2432482#2432482)). I would recommend a triangulation such as a [Delaunay Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) and then trivially compute the area of each triangle.  [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/planar_subdivisions.html?highlight=delaunay#cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D) (I've used it with a large number of 2D points and it's very effective) and [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) provide excellent implementations for determining the triangulation.

Answer (score 0):

I found another [function written in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28424660/1689197) , so i traslated it to C#

```
public static double area(List<Double> lats,List<Double> lons)
{       
double sum=0;
double prevcolat=0;
double prevaz=0;
double colat0=0;
double az0=0;
for (int i=0;i<lats.Count;i++)
{
    double colat=2*Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Sin(lats[i]*Math.PI/180/2), 2)+ Math.Cos(lats[i]*Math.PI/180)*Math.Pow(Math.Sin(lons[i]*Math.PI/180/2), 2)),
        Math.Sqrt(1-  Math.Pow(Math.Sin(lats[i]*Math.PI/180/2), 2)- Math.Cos(lats[i]*Math.PI/180)*Math.Pow(Math.Sin(lons[i]*Math.PI/180/2), 2)));
    double az=0;
    if (lats[i]>=90)
    {
        az=0;
    }
    else if (lats[i]<=-90)
    {
        az=Math.PI;
    }
    else
    {
        az=Math.Atan2(Math.Cos(lats[i]*Math.PI/180) * Math.Sin(lons[i]*Math.PI/180),Math.Sin(lats[i]*Math.PI/180))% (2*Math.PI);
    }
    if(i==0)
    {
         colat0=colat;
         az0=az;
    }           
    if(i>0 && i<lats.Count)
    {
        sum=sum+(1-Math.Cos(prevcolat  + (colat-prevcolat)/2))*Math.PI*((Math.Abs(az-prevaz)/Math.PI)-2*Math.Ceiling(((Math.Abs(az-prevaz)/Math.PI)-1)/2))* Math.Sign(az-prevaz);
    }
    prevcolat=colat;
    prevaz=az;
}
sum=sum+(1-Math.Cos(prevcolat  + (colat0-prevcolat)/2))*(az0-prevaz);
return 5.10072E14* Math.Min(Math.Abs(sum)/4/Math.PI,1-Math.Abs(sum)/4/Math.PI);
}
```