# C# equivalent of computeArea of Google Maps API

Tags: c#, math, geometry, gis

Google Maps Api has a [google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html#Distance) method.
How can I write its equivalent in C#? (What will be the formula)

I have a set of lat long values for which I need to calculate area (in meters) of the enclosed polygon.

Sample code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried yourself?

There are some very similar questions with detailed answers, so it's best to refer to them:

- [Polygon area calculation using Latitude and Longitude generated from Cartesian space and a world file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861272/polygon-area-calculation-using-latitude-and-longitude-generated-from-cartesian-sp)
- [Calculating area enclosed by arbitrary polygon on Earth's surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340223/calculating-area-enclosed-by-arbitrary-polygon-on-earths-surface)

Comment: I want equivalent of that method. Can't try something until I know whats going on in that method. Which projection it is using etc. I have already written a method but results are different and this questions is not about whats wrong with my implementation but rather what is going on inside that method if someone knows.

Comment: Refer to the links which are answering the same problem you are facing. I don't think the exact algorithm that Google uses is stated anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for adding an answer to an old question, but if someone else is looking for a quickly answer:

```
private const double EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137;

public class LatLng
{
    public double latitude { get; private set; }
    public double longitude { get; private set; }

    public LatLng(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}

public static double computeArea(List<LatLng> path)
{
    return Math.Abs(computeSignedArea(path));
}

private static double computeSignedArea(List<LatLng> path, double radius = EARTH_RADIUS)
{
    int size = path.Count;
    if (size < 3) { return 0; }
    double total = 0;
    LatLng prev = path[size - 1];
    double prevTanLat = Math.Tan((Math.PI / 2 - toRadians(prev.latitude)) / 2);
    double prevLng = toRadians(prev.longitude);
    // For each edge, accumulate the signed area of the triangle formed by the North Pole
    // and that edge ("polar triangle").
    foreach (LatLng point in path)
    {
        double tanLat = Math.Tan((Math.PI / 2 - toRadians(point.latitude)) / 2);
        double lng = toRadians(point.longitude);
        total += polarTriangleArea(tanLat, lng, prevTanLat, prevLng);
        prevTanLat = tanLat;
        prevLng = lng;
    }
    return total * (radius * radius);
}

private static double polarTriangleArea(double tan1, double lng1, double tan2, double lng2)
{
    double deltaLng = lng1 - lng2;
    double t = tan1 * tan2;
    return 2 * Math.Atan2(t * Math.Sin(deltaLng), 1 + t * Math.Cos(deltaLng));
}

private static double toRadians(double input)
{
    return input * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Reference [https://github.com/googlemaps](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/9085396a1cb5703db568241937ffa330ff099d4e/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the formula from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polygon).