# Area of Concave Polygon with Latitude Longitude

Tags: .net, 2d, latitude-longitude

I have been racking my brains for a little while to figure out a way of computing the area of a concave polygon. I already have code that copes with convex (by splitting into triangles) but obviously this will not work.

So far I have tried the following approaches:

- Project Lat Lon values via ESPG 3395. Use these values in cross product or alternatively use methodology explained [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/area-irregular-polygons.html).

I have found several related stack overflow articles with answers but I don’t truely understand which is the most appropriate way.

To validate the answers, I’ve been using google my maps, with the coordinates added and a polygon drawn giving me the area in km^2.

Here are the related articles I’ve found:

1. [Calculate Area of Polygon with Latitude and Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022883/calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-with-latitude-and-longitude)

Is projecting them and then using vector maths the most appropriate or am I required to use spherical maths?

Comment: Found few more articles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838187/polygon-area-calculation-using-latitude-and-longitude. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340223/calculating-area-enclosed-by-arbitrary-polygon-on-earths-surface  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646760/c-sharp-equivalent-of-computearea-of-google-maps-api/7646847#7646847

Comment: Now evaluating whether to use Eckert IV projection or Lambert azimuthal projection.