# Android how to calculate area of gps location

Tags: android, gps

I am developing field area calculator app using gps location.Is there any way to calculate the 
area of given gps locations?

Comment: GPS location is a POINT & you cannot have a Area of a point. So you need to have atleast 3 GPS-points to calculate area.

Comment: I have more than one gps locations or point.

Comment: What will be the maximum diameter of the area?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1340223/813951

Comment: The Google Maps JavaScript API [Polygon module](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.0/com/google/gwt/maps/client/overlay/Polygon.html) has a getArea function, but the [equivalent class](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html) in Android does not seem to have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the area of an polygon that is formed by a sequence of GPS coordinates.

The steps are:

1. transform the spherical lat/lon coordinates to cartesian space.
2. Use the general formula for area of polygon.

Code is given in this answer:
[Polygon area calculation using Latitude and Longitude generated from Cartesian space and a world file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861272/polygon-area-calculation-using-latitude-and-longitude-generated-from-cartesian-s)

Use the center of the polygon (or just any point of the polygon) as center of transformation.
In the code in the link, that is called `latAnchor` and `lonAnchor`.

Especially if the diameter of the polygon does not exceed some 10 kilometers this approach works well. For large polygons step 1 becomes more complex.