# Getting area from GPS coordinates

Tags: java, gps

So, I've got a method that returns the area of a shape defined by its points (given in CCW or CW order, it doesn't really matter). I tested it with some shapes and it seems to be working.

The problem is, I want to use this method with GPS coordinates, and I want to return the result in m² or km², but that's definitly not what happens. In fact, I don't even know in which unit the result is when I use this method with that kind of coordinates.

So the question is, how to convert the result I have into m² or km² ? I tried some things, but either it does not work or it's inaccurate.

Here's my method, if you want to check :

```
public static double getArea(List<Vector2D> points) {

    double firstSum = 0, secondSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < points.size()-1 ; i++) {
        firstSum += points.get(i).x * points.get(i+1).y;
        secondSum += points.get(i).y * points.get(i+1).x;
    }
    firstSum += points.get( points.size()-1 ).x * points.get(0).y;
    secondSum += points.get( points.size()-1 ).y * points.get(0).x;

    return Math.abs((firstSum-secondSum)/2);

}
```

(`Vector2D` is the class I use for points, with `x` as the latitude and `y` as the longitude)

Comment: @AndyTurner Are you sure it's a duplicate? The "duplicate" is about [tag:google-maps].

Comment: If you want a result in m² or km² you first have to convert your GPS coordinates (which are probably lon/lat) to some metric coordinate reference system.

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry. I'll remove this question. Thanks by the way !

Comment: I think the question is OK.

Comment: Is it still a duplicate, so ?

Comment: The [previous duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022883/calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-with-latitude-and-longitude) contains code to calculate the area of a polygon in lat/lng. It's not in Java, but it's hardly a stretch to convert it. Several other questions on other stackexchange sites can be found easily by searching on your favorite search engine.

Comment: @AndyTurner *"The [previous duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022883/calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-with-latitude-and-longitude) contains code to calculate the area of a polygon in lat/lng."* - that code is basically `GpsHelper.CalculatePolygonArea(poly)` which you can't really convert to Java without diving into the implementation of `GpsHelper.CalculatePolygonArea`. This is why I object it being a duplicate.

Comment: @lexicore "which you can't really convert to Java without diving into the implementation" the implementation that's right there, you mean? Just change the types, change the trig methods to the `java.lang.Math` equivalents... it's really not hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not taking the (approximately) spherical nature of the Earth into account. For a start, you need to take into account the radius of the Earth - you could have the same list of latitude and longitude on a smaller (or bigger) planet, but the radius would be different, and consequently the area would be different too.

You can use the approach [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022883/calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-with-latitude-and-longitude). It's trivial to convert that to Java:

```
public static double CalculatePolygonArea(List<Vector2D> coordinates)
{
    double area = 0;

    if (coordinates.size() > 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size()-1; i++)
        {
            Vector2D p1, p2;
            p1 = coordinates.get(i);
            p2 = coordinates.get(i + 1);
            area += Math.toRadians(p2.x - p1.x) * (2 + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(p1.y))
               + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(p2.y)));

        }
        area = area * R * R / 2;
    }

    return Math.abs(area);
}
```

(assuming `Vector2D.x` is the longitude and `Vector2D.y` is the latitude).

`R` is the radius of the Earth. Use a value in the unit you want the area result to be in (e.g. 6_371_000 metres for square metres, 6_371 km for square km, 3_959 miles for square miles...)

Comment: Yes, I've been doing this since you mentionned the other question, I'm currently testing this with my values