# Polygon area calculation using Latitude and Longitude

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, geolocation

I am using a solution I've found in this post:
[Polygon area calculation using Latitude and Longitude generated from Cartesian space and a world file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861272/polygon-area-calculation-using-latitude-and-longitude-generated-from-cartesian-s)

[image: Denver football field]

There is something wrong because the values I am getting are not real. For example we know a football field should have around 5,300.00 square meters, right? but the calculation is giving 5,759,154.21.

This is the code:

```
    private static double CalculatePolygonArea(IList<Position> coordinates)
    {
        double area = 0;

        if (coordinates.Count > 2)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Position p1 = coordinates[i];
                Position p2 = coordinates[i + 1];
                area += (ConvertToRadian(p2.Longitude) - ConvertToRadian(p1.Longitude)) * (2 + Math.Sin(ConvertToRadian(p1.Latitude)) + Math.Sin(ConvertToRadian(p2.Latitude)));
            }

            area = area * 6378137 * 6378137 / 2;
        }

        return Math.Abs(area);
    }

    private static double ConvertToRadian(double input)
    {
        return input * Math.PI / 180;
    }
```

What can be wrong here? Any help?

Comment: what are the values of your 4 points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The area calculation you are using is just plain wrong.... :-/

I use the [`SphericalUtil.ComputeSignedArea`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/7368f6157560c6d132de55f27e1147cd6a43c961/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java#L222) method from Google's Android Maps Utils.

Note: Google's Java code for that is under Apache License Version 2.0, and I converted it to C#.

Looking up that football field up in one of my apps, I get: 4,461, not quite the *actual* 5,531 but not bad for using Google Map photos...

[image]

Here is just the `ComputeSignedArea`:

```
public static class SphericalUtil
{
    const double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371009;

    static double ToRadians(double input)
    {
        return input / 180.0 * Math.PI;
    }

    public static double ComputeSignedArea(IList<LatLng> path)
    {
        return ComputeSignedArea(path, EARTH_RADIUS);
    }

    static double ComputeSignedArea(IList<LatLng> path, double radius)
    {
        int size = path.Count;
        if (size < 3) { return 0; }
        double total = 0;
        var prev = path[size - 1];
        double prevTanLat = Math.Tan((Math.PI / 2 - ToRadians(prev.Latitude)) / 2);
        double prevLng = ToRadians(prev.Longitude);

        foreach (var point in path)
        {
            double tanLat = Math.Tan((Math.PI / 2 - ToRadians(point.Latitude)) / 2);
            double lng = ToRadians(point.Longitude);
            total += PolarTriangleArea(tanLat, lng, prevTanLat, prevLng);
            prevTanLat = tanLat;
            prevLng = lng;
        }
        return total * (radius * radius);
    }

    static double PolarTriangleArea(double tan1, double lng1, double tan2, double lng2)
    {
        double deltaLng = lng1 - lng2;
        double t = tan1 * tan2;
        return 2 * Math.Atan2(t * Math.Sin(deltaLng), 1 + t * Math.Cos(deltaLng));
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool - working for me sometimes, but other times this returns a negative result. Should we just take the ABS of the result? Or is something else going on? My points seem to be ordered correctly I.e. first point is the same as the last point.

Comment: Checking my numbers against known values, when I'm getting negatives, the scalar component seems accurate and as expected. So I've added Math.Abs around your return statement.