# How to get square meter or square km using in html5 / ionic

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, geolocation, gps

Here is what I am thinking. I want to get user location using GPS. Instead of sending current position I want to calculate square km or meter.

```
----------------------------------
|                                |
|                                |
|                                | 
|                                |
|              .                 |
|              ^                 |
|      My current position       |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
----------------------------------
```

As you can see in figure above, my current position but I want to calculate the whole area around that in HTML5 or Ionic would be more preferred.

Update

[image]

In above image the red dot is my position and I need to get the whole area in red rectangle. Get that store that in database. I looked into the Polygon area formulas but that requires several vertices, with geolocation I only get longitude and latitude just two coordinates. How am I gonna do that using these two points?

UPDATE

I found a solution [here](https://gist.github.com/bmoren/22470de1cd47410e0902) but this solution is keep tracking user's current location and in `calculateDistance` function the formula uses both current location (longitude and latitude) and tracking location(longitude and latitude) i.e. `Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);`

This works perfectly fine for my second scenario but first I do not want to track user's location at first. First I simple get current user location(longitude and latitude), calculate the area from that and send it to server. Now I am not sure how am I going to achieve that. Any help?

Comment: The thing is that the region is not a rectangle. The Earth is a sphere so you would have to either use a library or [do the math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5820404/283863) yourself.

Comment: try to find out geofence I think this will be helpful.

Comment: How do you want your data to be like? Do you want to calculate the square km of that area? Do you want lat-lng coordinates of the corners? Please provide your question with the desired output

Comment: @Ivaro18 I do not want to draw any rectangle, I just want to get current location of user, then find its polygon/area about lets say 1000 meter square and send that as json to server where I will store. Later when user, I will track users location based on GPS and when they get into that range I will show them a message the you are in that range. Thats all.

Comment: Ok so if you have the middle point in lat-lng, can't you just calculate the lat & long values of 1km and add & substract them to create your corners of the polygon?

Comment: @Ivaro18 I can but that is my weak point :( calculation.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Depending on what database you are using, you might be able to send the point to the database and then use database functions to get the radius/then bounding box similar to the answer by @Makore.  In this case you would have less storage, quicker inserts but slower queries.

Answer (score 6):

I've created a circle in google maps and then got his bounds, which return a square bounding boxes.

```js
function getBounds(latLng, radius) {
  /*
  * Params:
  *     latLng: google maps LatLng object or object literal  // example: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }
  *     radius: Number(int) in Miters. For example 1000 will be 1 sq Kilometer
  * Returns:
  *     object literal in the following format:
  *         {
                northEast: {
                  lat: (float),
                  lng: (float),
                },
                southWest: {
                  lat: (float),
                  lng: (float),
                },
            }
  * */

  const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: latLng,
    radius: radius
  });
  const bounds = circle.getBounds();
  const northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
  const southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
  return {
    northEast: {
      lat: northEast.lat(),
      lng: northEast.lng(),
    },
    southWest: {
      lat: southWest.lat(),
      lng: southWest.lng(),
    },
  };
}
```

I took the library to add a short snippet for you to see if this is the right answer for what you were looking for. 
Once you click on the map you will see a marker and the triangle around it.

**Note**: Please copy the code and add your google map API key. **Without your API key, the map will fail to load.**

```js
let map;
let marker;
let rectangle;

function initMap() {
  const latLng = {
    lat: -34.397,
    lng: 150.644
  };
  const radius = 1000;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 11,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    const location = event.latLng;
    const bounds = getBounds(location, 1000);
    console.log(bounds);
    addRectangle(bounds);
    addMarker(location);
  });
}

function addMarker(location) {
  if (marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  }
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
}

function addRectangle(bounds) {
  if (rectangle) {
    rectangle.setMap(null);
  }
  rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    bounds: {
      north: bounds.northEast.lat,
      south: bounds.southWest.lat,
      east: bounds.northEast.lng,
      west: bounds.southWest.lng,
    },
  });
}

function getBounds(latLng, radius) {
  /*
  * Params:
  *     latLng: google maps LatLng object or object literal  // example: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }
  *     radius: Number(int) in Miters. For example 1000 will be 1 sq Kilometer
  * Returns:
  *     object literal in the following format:
  *         {
                northEast: {
                  lat: (float),
                  lng: (float),
                },
                southWest: {
                  lat: (float),
                  lng: (float),
                },
            }
  * */

  const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: latLng,
    radius: radius
  });
  const bounds = circle.getBounds();
  const northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
  const southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
  return {
    northEast: {
      lat: northEast.lat(),
      lng: northEast.lng(),
    },
    southWest: {
      lat: southWest.lat(),
      lng: southWest.lng(),
    },
  };
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
         * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ll give it a try but when I try to get google maps API key it asks me to provide credit card details. I cannot proceed further without details :(. Is there any other solution without Google maps API?

Comment: I’ll try to come out with another solution. Do you use any map engine in the client (like google maps or leaflet)?

Comment: No I am not using any maps yet but my plan was to use google maps which is now seems to be hard because of my above reply.

Comment: I just gave a look to leaflet which seems good. Maybe I ll give it a try.