# Calculate spherical polygon area?

Tags: c++, math

I have used "**Girard's Theorem**" to calculate the area of spherical polygon with great circle edges, as stated in a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340223/calculating-area-enclosed-by-arbitrary-polygon-on-earths-surface/1342706#1342706).

In most cases, it works fine, but I encounters a negative area case. The coordinate (lon/lat) of those vertices in counterclockwise are (radian):

5.240747351 1.016447132

5.268216612 1.067869338

5.216315614 1.072132414

5.129855176 1.00109075

5.080803026 0.950935874

5.134615486 0.9460488828

and I plotted the polygon using NCL (Sorry, I couldn't post image right now :()

As you can see, the interior angle 4 is nearly 180 degree (179.77708422692623). The calculated excess is -0.16533548347651544 in degree. Any idea? If you need to see code, I can post them later. :)

Comment: I really don't get your point. What is the question? If you have a 0.1 degree error in _something_ you probably have to revise the precision used in your calculations.

Comment: The question I am asking is that why do I get "negative" area in this case. I used "double" type.

Comment: I think you have an oxymoron in your title: a sphere has one side, but a polygon means "multiple sides." Also, it's *volume* and not *area*, when in terms of a 3-dimensional object.

Comment: "Spherical polygon" means a polygon embedded on the surface of a sphere, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalPolygon.html. There is no contradictory~ And it is really "area".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out! The problematic interior angle is not ~179 but ~181, due to the value range of "acos" is [0, PI]. So some judgement should be conducted for each angle (whether the calculated angle is interior or exterior).