# Calculate Earth convex hull polygon area given latitude and longitude

Tags: java, geocoding, latitude-longitude, area, geography

I have searched for explanations and algorhitms how to calculate Earth's polygon surface area. I've found [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080213175333AASYvUd) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681737/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-on-the-earths-surface-using-python)
Lets say I got already convex hull points
`[56.992666,24.126051], [58.00282,25.930147], [58.787955,25.565078], [59.4997,24.861427], [59.463678,24.711365], [59.395767,24.599837], [56.992666,24.126051]`

From second link the first answers uses Python library and second answer approach won't give quite precise area even if we assume that Earth is sphere (am I right)?
What approaches could I take for calculating the area (less expensive) if we assume that Earth is sphere?

In addition, I have looked for different libraries (geotools.org etc) but haven't found in their documentation about area calculation.

Comment: This looks useful: http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=20724

Comment: And this was referenced in the worldwind thread: http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/40409/1/07-03.pdf

Comment: @TreyA Thank you very much for directions! Reading the PDF now. Sadly the algorhitm in the forum post gave me totally wrong answer. I checked answer here http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-area-calculator-tool.htm with my points and correct one is ~15200km2 but the algorhitm gave over 5 000 000. The latitude-longitude pairs are in my post

Comment: @TreyA Hey the algorhitm in the forum is working one. I forgot to convert my latitude-longitude degrees to radians beforehand.
You can write your reply as an answer and i would accept that.

Comment: @Skyzer In above link how to calculate spherical radius?. Is it earth's spherical radius if so which value to use for that?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm for finding the area of a polygon on a sphere can be found here:
[Thread: A method to compute the area of a spherical polygon](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324191929/http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?20724-A-method-to-compute-the-area-of-a-spherical-polygon)

You could also use this NASA JPL paper for some algorithms:

[Some algorithms for polygons on a sphere.](https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/handle/2014/41271)

Comment: In above link how to calculate spherical radius?. Is it earth's spherical radius if so which value to use for that?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A typical value for the earth's radius is 6371km.

Comment: thanks for your reply I was stalked on this. It means in above link we have to "Spherical radius = r (earth's radius)" and area will be in square kms?

Comment: @TreyA NASA link broken. Any alternative ?