# `chull` for GPS coordinates?

Tags: r, geocoding, convex-hull

The function `chull` :

> Computes the subset of points which lie on the convex hull of the set
>   of points specified.

I can use it on latitudes and longitudes but the result won't be exact, because of the curvature of the Earth, how can I compute the equivalent `gps_chull` ?

---

Answers linked in the comments are not R answers. They give hints as to how we might design a R answer but are not it.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601816/calculate-earth-convex-hull-polygon-area-given-latitude-and-longitude/9612324#9612324

Comment: These are great links @dww thank you, however these are not tagged as R questions, if somebody comes up with a handy R function they won't be able to post it there, so I wouldn't say it qualifies as a duplicate.

Comment: There is the function `st_convex_hull` in the `sf` package. Also take a look at the [concaveman](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/concaveman/) package.