# How do i calculate area within a Contour line?

Tags: python, math, contour

I am trying to find the area within a Contour line.
I have 523 points in X,Y,Z-axis which form a closed irregular shape with these points. Z is being constant throughout the shape......
few points are array([[-33.328, -89.917, 171.   ],[-33.212, -90.032, 171.   ],     [-31.824, -90.032, 171.   ], [-34.022, -89.685, 171.   ], -33.907, -89.801, 171.   ], [-33.444, -89.801, 171.   ]])
I do not have an equation.
Does anyone have any idea how to find out the area in Python?

[shape formed with the points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwGIz.jpg)

Comment: How precise a result do you need? You could imagine your points are pixels, and count the number of pixels inside the contour.

Comment: it can be approximate and dont need an exact area

Answer (score -1):

The question is kind of [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681737/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-on-the-earths-surface-using-python).

In one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681737/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-on-the-earths-surface-using-python/4682656#4682656) inside this question the second part tells how to compute area of polygon by function `area_of_polygon(x, y)`

Where x and y are x and y coordinates of all points in the same order. Assuming that your array is points you can get this by:

```
x = points[:, 0]
y = points[:, 1]
```