# iphone -- convert MKMapPoint distances to meters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit

Say I have a square which consists of four CLLocationCoordinate2D points, which are in lat, lon, and I want to find the area of the square in meters.  I convert the CLLocationCoordinate2D points into MKMapPoints, and I find the area in X-Y space.  However, the area I find is in the units of MKMapPoint, which don't directly translate to meters.  How can I translate this area in MKMapPoint-space back into meters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MapKit function `MKMetersBetweenMapPoints` makes this easier.

For example, if you wanted to get the area of the currently displayed region:

```
MKMapPoint mpTopLeft = mapView.visibleMapRect.origin;

MKMapPoint mpTopRight = MKMapPointMake(
    mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x + mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width, 
    mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.y);

MKMapPoint mpBottomRight = MKMapPointMake(
    mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x + mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width, 
    mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.y + mapView.visibleMapRect.size.height);

CLLocationDistance hDist = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(mpTopLeft, mpTopRight);
CLLocationDistance vDist = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(mpTopRight, mpBottomRight);

double vmrArea = hDist * vDist;
```

The documentation states that the function takes "into account the curvature of the Earth."

Comment: ok thanks, this is pretty helpful.  but what if I have a irregular polygon?  There is a formula for the area of a polygon given the vertices, but I would be doing the calculation in MKMapPoint units.  How would I convert those to meters?

Comment: The question said "square" so I gave an example of a rectangular area.  Even then, _the above is still an approximation and only useful for relatively small areas_ where the curvature isn't a significant factor (though the _distance_ function is accurate regardless).  For irregular polygons, sorry I don't have a simple answer.  Try starting with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340223/calculating-area-enclosed-by-arbitrary-polygon-on-earths-surface).  You'll have to decide what algorithm you want to use and go from there.

Comment: Try this to calculate area of an irregular polygon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038925/mkpolygon-area-calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate it, assuming that the earth is a perfect sphere.

To understand how lat/lon vs meters works in the context of the earth, you may find it interesting to read about [Nautical miles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautical_mile).

You can find some more resources and some sample code by googling [objective-c Haversine formula](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=objective-c%20Haversine%20formula&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Enjoy!