# Get the MKMapView boundary in meters

Tags: ios, mapkit

How can I find out the size of the currently displayed area of MKMapKit view, ideally in meters?

MKMapKit has a `visibleMapRect` method which can be used to obtain a `MKMapSize`, for which the docs say:

> The units of this value are map points.

What is a "map point"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

[iphone -- convert MKMapPoint distances to meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395925/iphone-convert-mkmappoint-distances-to-meters)

Comment: @Abizern your comment is wrong. The linked answer explains the use of the function `MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude` which indeed answers the question.

Comment: @Grimxn: My comment was on the original answer which has since been edited Thanks. I've deleted the comment.