# How to calculate area inside multiple geo coordinates in android

Tags: android

In my application i am capturing all selected location gps coordinates,and also i am drawing line between each selected coordinates.

I already know how to calculate distance between two points

but in my application user may select any number of locations so i wants to calculate the area between all selected coordinates

can any one please tell me how to calculate area inside n number of coordinates.

And also please let me how to convert the resulting area into acres.

since from 2 days i am searching a lot to achieve this but not succeeded so please help me

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340223/calculating-area-enclosed-by-arbitrary-polygon-on-earths-surface