# Calculate Polygon area using Maps V2 on Android

Tags: android, maps, polygon, area

I'm using Google Maps Android API v2 and a polygon drawn on maps. Now I want to calculate the area of this polygon.

I know that Google Maps JavaScript API v3 has a simple way to do this, using: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(yourPolygon.getPath()).

Is there a similar way to calculate polygon area using Google Maps Android API v2? If no, wich method do you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

EDIT:

I found the following algorithm that seems to resolve my problem:

http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~pang/160/f98/Gems/GemsIV/sph_poly.c

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to do some math. There doesn't seem to be a method for that in the Google Maps Android API v2.

Check the following questions for possible help:

[Calculating area enclosed by arbitrary polygon on Earth's surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340223/calculating-area-enclosed-by-arbitrary-polygon-on-earths-surface)

[measure area of irregular polygon in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732854/measure-area-of-irregular-polygon-in-android)

[Calculate the area covered by a polygon in a google map in an Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057221/calculate-the-area-covered-by-a-polygon-in-a-google-map-in-an-android-app)

Comment: Hi Zabri!

Thanks for you reponses and the related topics already discussed here! I thought Google had a method to easily calculate this.

I will take a look on that!

Comment: I found this algorithm that seems to resolve the problem:

http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~pang/160/f98/Gems/GemsIV/sph_poly.c